# How to move instance zone in google cloud without running the VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

My VM in google cloud can't run due to below error has shown.

> "Starting VM instance failed. Error: The zone does not have enough
>   resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or
>   try again later."

Then I what to start VM from other zones by changing the zone of my VM by this  [method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) but it's required VM running.

The problem is I can't run the VM. How can I use another solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google's having issues with limited External IPs. Try removing the external IP before starting the instance. Then create an external IP and attach it your instance.

Comment: I try to use an external IP as ephemeral but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve just encountered a stockout issue. A Stockout means that the particular GCP datacenter in that zone has reached its resource limit.

The Google Cloud Platform team are there to make sure that there are available resources in all zones. This type of issue is rare. When a situation like this occurs or is about to occur, the team is notified immediately, the issue is investigated and quickly fixed.

I recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of a stockout. Please review [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on the Google Cloud Platform.

You may also try again later, once resources will be available again in the region.

This being said, I see that you’ve posted your question on November 9th.  That was a long time ago. Can you confirm if your issue is fixed now? It is very rare for stockouts to last this long.